# Redirect Streams

Tags: redirection, fish

I am trying to redirect the results of `rg` to `comm` to compare the match intersection. Fish seems to think that I will be passing a file path and and not the stream.

```
> comm -12 <(rg -l "\\bar\\b" | sort) <(rg -l "@" | sort)
fish: Invalid redirection target: (rg -l "\\bar\\b" | sort)
comm -12 <(rg -l "\\bar\\b" | sort) <(rg -l "@" | sort)
         ^
fish: Invalid redirection target: (rg -l "@" | sort)
comm -12 <(rg -l "\\bar\\b" | sort) <(rg -l "@" | sort)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`comm -12 <( … ) <( … )` works in Bash but I believe the right syntax in `fish` is like

```
comm -12 ( … | psub ) ( … | psub )
```

Yes, [`psub` belongs to the syntax](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#psub).